# Python inheritance for lists of instances

Tags: python, arrays, list, class, inheritance

I have a python object, with many attributes and functions (dummy example bellow):

```
class molecule:
     def __init__(self, atoms, coords):
         self.atoms=np.copy(atoms)
         self.coords=np.copy(coords)

     def shift(self,r):
         self.coords=self.coords+r
```

I would like to generate preferably a `numpy` array (or a `list`) of these objects and to obtain its properties without always looping over the array. At the moment I create a list of molecule objects (`mols`) by a loop and check its attributes by loops eg:

```
atomList=[mol.atoms for mol in mols]
```

but I would prefer to obtain it as:

```
atomList=mols.atoms
```

Is there an automatic way to obtain such an array/list class without manually defining the `molList` class and manually add its attributes, functions etc?

Comment: Other than defining an `atoms` function, which takes a list of molecules, I don't think there is a neater way of doing this. I would just keep using list comprehensions.

Comment: Are you just looking for a way to hide the list comprehension so you don't have to type it every time (use a function) or do you want a way to avoid a list comprehension entirely? Is there a way you can represent a molecule as a `np` array?

Comment: The molecules are defined as objects which has properties that are tipically numpy arrays. I already have dozens of functions that operates on them.  I just started to work with  too many molecules that I cannot anymore define as mol1,..., mol150 one by one, I need to use a molList. I would like to choose then from them based on properties (eg. max energy etc) or randomly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `class_variable`. The difference between class variables and instance variables can be found here:
[https://medium.com/python-features/class-vs-instance-variables-8d452e9abcbd#:~:text=Class%20variables%20are%20shared%20across,surprising%20behaviour%20in%20our%20code](https://medium.com/python-features/class-vs-instance-variables-8d452e9abcbd#:%7E:text=Class%20variables%20are%20shared%20across,surprising%20behaviour%20in%20our%20code).

For your example, something like this ought to work:

```py
class molecule:
    atomList = []  # class variable
    def __init__(self, atoms, coords):
        self.atoms=np.copy(atoms)  # instance variable
        self.coords=np.copy(coords)
        molecule.atomList.append(atoms) # update the class variable with each new instance of the class

    def shift(self,r):
        self.coords=self.coords+r
```

Then in your code, you can just do `atomlist = molecule.atomList`

Comment: Note: This gives _all_ the atoms in _all_ the molecules ever created.

Comment: The aim is to obtain a list or array of ANY property or to access ANY function of the object instances without manually coding some function etc. for the given property.